# Discord.js Edit embed

Tags: discord.js

I am trying to edit an embed sent previously by the bot with updated roles but it gives the error in discord v12
DiscordAPIError: Cannot edit a message authored by another user

[image: What the message is that I am trying to edit]

```
if(message.content === "editroles"){
        let embed = new discord.MessageEmbed()
            .setTitle('Server Events')
            .setDescription('Announcements:\nReact with  to get pinged for announcements!\n\nEvents:\nReact with ️ to get pinged for server events!\n\nPolls:\nReact with  to get pinged for daily polls!')
            .setColor('DARK_BUT_NOT_BLACK')
        message.channel.messages.fetch({around: '806426175609110529', limit: 1})
        .then(msg => {
            const embededit = msg.first()
            embededit.edit(embed);
        })
    }
```

Comment: Are you sure you are connecting with the same bot account ?

Comment: Yes I am sure it is the same bot

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to use:

```
message.channel.messages.fetch('806426175609110529')
```

This fetches the Message Directly and makes sure it is always the message with that exact id.

If this errors, it could be that `message.channel` is not the same channel where the embed was sent.

I played *around* with `around:` and it seems to not be 100% reliable.

Comment: Thank you for your help that worked with the command

Comment: No problem! If this answer solved your Question make sure to mark your Question as solved by marking this answer with the Green Tick as the accepted answer.